# react-map-gl center of the map doesn`t change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl, react-map-gl

I'm using node(16.17.0) and react(17.0.1).

And the issue is react-map-gl(7.0.19)

The latitude and longitude change well, but the map can't move to the center to location.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    setViewState({
        latitude:center?.lat,
        longitude:center?.lng,
        zoom: 18,
    })
},[center]);

<ReactMapGL
    initialViewState={viewState}
    onMove={onMove}
    onViewportChange={(viewport) => setViewState(viewport)}
    mapboxAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
    mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
>
    <Source type={"geojson"} data={returnGeoData()} >
        <Layer type={"fill"} paint={{
            'fill-color': '#0080ff', // blue color fill
            'fill-opacity': 0.5
        }} />
        <Layer type={"line"} paint={{
            'line-color': '#0938d0',
            'line-width': 3
        }} />
    </Source>
    {/*{*/}
    {/*    !isEmpty(rotatedPoly?.geometry?.coordinates[0]?.slice(0,4)) &&*/}
    {/*    <Source  type="image" url={testImg} coordinates={rotatedPoly?.geometry?.coordinates[0]?.slice(0,4)}  >*/}
    {/*        <Layer source={"testItem"} type={"raster"} paint={{*/}
    {/*            "raster-fade-duration":0*/}
    {/*        }}/>*/}
    {/*    </Source>*/}
    {/*}*/}
</ReactMapGL>
```

Is there a reason why the map can't go to center even change a 'setViewState'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the map view to update dynamically based on your center value, the `ReactMapGl` component needs to include the `viewState` properties (latitude, longitude, zoom). You can simply fix it by adding `{...viewState}` like this:

```
<ReactMapGL
    {...viewState}
    initialViewState={viewState}
    onMove={onMove}
    onViewportChange={(viewport) => setViewState(viewport)}
    mapboxAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
    mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
>
```

Besides, I suggest using a static value instead of `viewState` for your `initialViewState`.

Comment: Thanys for your help.